# How to write this kind of colour text in LaTeX?

Tags: color, text, text-decorations, text-manipulation

I need to add following text to my latex document. currently I created some image and add it to document.

I need to know some simple way to adding it as text , to my latest project.

An additional need is to center it on the page and to use a font size that's larger than defualt font. (My document default text sixe 12pt.) No need to add a border.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your typesetting objectives. E.g., would you like uppercase letters rendered in red automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \Large\sl
    \textcolor{red}{S}ince \textcolor{red}{E}veryone \textcolor{red}{C}an \textcolor{red}{R}ead, \textcolor{red}{E}ncoding \textcolor{red}{T}ext \textcolor{red}{I}n \textcolor{red}{N}eutral \textcolor{red}{S}entences \textcolor{red}{I}s \textcolor{red}{D}oubtfully \textcolor{red}{E}ffective

    \vspace{1cm}\LARGE\color{red}
    `Secret inside'
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: it out put as i exptect. are ther any wa to reduced gap between 'secrect inside' and about text

Comment: Do you mean the gap between "...Effective" and "secret inside" or the space after "secret inside"?

Comment: ya..i will manage it, :) thank you

Answer (score 5):

I've noticed that the OP has already accepted one of the answers provided so far. Just to provide some variety, here's a solution that provides a LaTeX macro called `\boldredcaps` which renders all uppercase letters in its argument in bold and red *automatically*. No need to apply lots of `\textbf{\textcolor{red}{...}}` instructions by hand. The LaTeX macro `\boldredcaps` relies on Lua's powerful `gsub` string function to accomplish its job.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}   % for "\textcolor" macro
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for "\Centering" macro
\usepackage{luacode}  % for "\luaexec" macro
%% Define a LaTeX macro called "\boldredcaps":
\newcommand\boldredcaps[1]{\luaexec{%
   yyy = "#1"
   yyy = yyy:gsub ( "\%u" , "\\textbf{\\textcolor{red}{\%0}}" )
   tex.sprint ( yyy )
}}

%% Concoct steganographic message:
\newcommand{\blurb}{Since Everyone Can Read, Encoding Text In Neutral Sentences Is Doubtfully Effective.}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\Large  % or "\large", or "\huge", etc
\sffamily\itshape
\Centering
\boldredcaps{\blurb} % <-- argument of \boldredcaps can be a macro 

\bigskip
\textbf{\textcolor{red}{`secret inside'}}
\rmfamily\upshape
\caption{Text Steganography}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you need to do this often, it can be automated with the `xstring` using `\StrSubstitute` to replace a space with `\textcolor{red}`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand*{\Hightlight}[1]{%
    \noexpandarg
    \StrSubstitute[0]{\textcolor{red}#1}{ }{ \textcolor{red}}[\FormattedString]%
    \FormattedString%
}%

\begin{document}
\Hightlight{Since Everyone Can Read, Encoding Text In Neutral Sentences Is Doubtfully Effective} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The provided code should give you the enclosed picture. Does it fit with what you wanted? You can tweak the code as you wish.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}

\begin{document}
\begin{framed}
\centering
\textbf{\color{red} S}ince \textbf{\color{red} E}veryone \textbf{\color{red} C}an \textbf{\color{red} R}ead, \textbf{\color{red} E}ncoding \textbf{\color{red} T}ext \textbf{\color{red} I}n \textbf{\color{red} N}eutral \textbf{\color{red} S}entences \textbf{\color{red} I}s \textbf{\color{red} D}oubtfully \textbf{\color{red} E}ffective. \\ \vspace{5mm}
{\large \textbf{\color{red} 'Secret inside'}}
\end{framed}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: are there any way remove this black border?

Comment: Just remove the `\begin{framed}` and `\end{framed}`. As your enclosed figure contained a frame, I included a frame, too.